# arreglos de selects multiples

Tags: php, web

Hola especialistas y expertos del tema, gracias de antemano por su siempre útil ayuda, hoy traigo un tema que no he podido resolver y espero me puedan ayudar porque no encuentro en que me estoy equivocando.
 Tengo una serie de n selects determinados por la variable $regcue, el formulario detecta y muestra los 7 selects y permite la selección de sus opciones, de esta forma:

```
@$p2ap=$_POST['p2ap'];
@$p2ap1=array();
//despues de una busqueda en una base de datos se determina que:
$regcue=7;
$respb=array('Siempre','Casi siempre','Casi nunca','Nunca','');
for($x1 = 0; $x1 < $regcue; $x1++)
{    
      echo '<td><select name="p2ap[$x1]" value="$p2ap[$x1]">';              
      for($x1a = 0; $x1a < count($respb); $x1a++)
      {
            if($respb[$x1a] == $_POST['p2ap[$x1a]']){$selected = ' selected';}
            else{$selected = '';}           
            echo '<option value="'.$respb[$x1a].'"'.$selected.'>'.$respb[$x1a].'</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
     @$p2v=$p2ap['$x1'];
      array_push($p2ap1,$p2v);                               
 }
echo " <td><input type='submit' name='botonenv' value='Continuar a la parte 3' >";  
if (@$_POST['botonenv']=='Continuar a la parte 3') {print_r($p2ap1);}
```

Al presionar el submit el problema es que no me esta tomando los valores de los selects del arreglo y solo retiene el valor del ultimo select (en este caso "Nunca") y obtengo como resultado:

```
Array ( [0] => Nunca [1] => Nunca [2] => Nunca [3] => Nunca [4] => Nunca [5] => Nunca [6] => Nunca )
```

el resultado se repite en todo el arreglo con el valor del ultimo select aun cuando los 6 anteriores son de valores distintos

podrian ayudarme a saber en donde me estoy equivocando?????

por su gran ayuda como siempre, Gracias. y reciban un cordial saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuación te dejo tu código solucionando algunos errores que he ido viendo, he comentado las líneas que he ido cambiando. No se si esto es la solución al 100%, pero hará más fácil todo.

Como consejo: intenta mantener el código limpio y legible, y evitar usar el `@`, suprimir errores no hará que se vayan, solo hará que no sepas donde esta mal.

```php
$p2ap = $_POST['p2ap']; // En lugar de suprimir errores con @, deberias mirar donde fallan y corregirlos, te ayudara a encontrar el fallo más facilmente

$p2ap1 = array();

//despues de una busqueda en una base de datos se determina que:
//
$regcue = 7;

$respb = array('Siempre','Casi siempre','Casi nunca','Nunca','');

for($x1 = 0; $x1 < $regcue; $x1++)
{    

    echo '<td><select name="p2ap[]"'; // Para usar variables dentro de un string, tienes que usar doble comillas. No es necesario meter el indice del array, ya que estamos imprimiendolos en orden. El value no pinta nada en el select, para elegir su valor, tienes que usar selected en la opcion

    for($x1a = 0; $x1a < count($respb); $x1a++)
    {

        if ($respb[$x1a] == $p2ap[$x1a]) // Ya que tenemos una variable con el parametro post que necesitamos, hagamos uso de ella. 
        {

            $selected = ' selected';

        }
        else
        {

            $selected = '';

        }           

        echo '<option value="' . $respb[$x1a]. '"' . $selected . '>' . $respb[$x1a] . '</option>';

    }

    echo '</select></td>'; // Se te olvida cerrar el td

    $p2v = $p2ap[$x1]; // Estas entrando a un indice del array llamado '$x1'. El @ te suprime el error

    array_push($p2ap1, $p2v);       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Francisco, eres un master

Efectivamente había varios errores y poca elegancia en el código, gracias a estas correcciones que me haces porque las llevare a la práctica.
Con lo que me dices decidi descartar algunas cosas (espero que haya entendido estos buenos habitos de codificación) quedando el código asi:

```
 $p2ap=$_POST['p2ap'];
 //elimine $p2ap1 porque los valores resultantes ya están en $p2ap
 //despues de una busqueda en una base de datos se determina que:
 $regcue = 7;
 $respb = array('Siempre','Casi siempre','Casi nunca','Nunca','');
 for($x1 = 0; $x1 < $regcue; $x1++)
 {
    echo '<td><select name="p2ap[]">'; //como lo recomendaste, **** esto fue la solucion     
    for($x1a = 0; $x1a < count($respb); $x1a++)
    {
       if($respb[$x1a] == $p2ap[$x1a])  //uso del post como lo recomiendas
       {
          $selected = ' selected';   //uso de los renglones
       }
       Else
       {
          $selected = '';
       }           
       echo '<option value="'.$respb[$x1a].'"'.$selected.'>'.$respb[$x1a].'</option>';
    } 
    echo '</select></td>'; //cerrando td
 }
 // ya que en $p2ap se encuentran los valores del arreglo, ya no es necesario crear otro donde inserte el valor de cada variable eliminando $p2v, $p2ap1 y el array_push()
```

Esto funciona tal como lo quería porque necesitaba un arreglo con los valores de cada select.
Estoy en lo correcto???? O sugieres algo mejor????
Gracias infinitas por tu ayuda y eres el mejor, me ayudaste de varios días estancado, seguimos en contacto y mas gracias.

Comment: Hay 20 mil maneras de hacer las cosas, asi que no puedo sugerirte "algo mejor", lo unico que puedo decirte es: escribe el código, como si lo fuese a leer alguien nuevo. A mas claro y limpio sea, más fácil será encontrar los problemas. Y no ocultes los errores, mejor solucionarlos que si no nos afectaras más adelante.